# ComboBox and EnableViewState="false"

Tags: c#, asp.net, obout

Note: I am fairly new with `ASP.NET`

I have a form with two `ComboBoxes` and one `ASP.NET CheckBox` list.

I am running into issues outlined as follows:

Though the query was accurate(confirmed by setting breakpoints and hovering over the query and everything step by step) the second ComboBox would not filter by the selected value of the first dropdown. I was then advised to set `EnableViewState` to false, which I did.

It all worked very nicely, the first `ComboBox` filtered the second one and the second `ComboBox` populated the Asp list. The issue now is that the checkboxes selected by the user in the asp list are being deselected after a postback.

When I set `EnableViewState` to true the checkboxes just refresh, but the second `ComboBox` does not filter.

Any ideas on what might resolve this issue?

Thank you so  much in advance!

Comment: Post some code so we can look at what your doing...

Comment: You said you are using a ComboBox, are you actually using a plugin to create a ComboBox from the "AspTxtBox" in your code above.  If so, we'll need more details about this plugin and need your code showing how you are triggering the filtering on the second ComboBox.

Comment: Alright I will try and get everything I pasted most of it already have another glimpse

Comment: The naming convention is a bit different from what I posted before, but the code is exactly the same.

Comment: The Asp List is not a combobox, it is a checkbox list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was because of the type of `ComboBox` I was using (Obout), though I did not think it was. The `OboutComboBox` needs to have its controls cleared before it is binded after a post back. (So the load function needed this line of code to work: `ComoboBox2.Controls.Clear();`)  This way one can leave EnableViewState to true.

I hope this helps anyone using the Obout conrol struggling with the same issue.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing code, it's hard to guess what's happening.  My hunch is that you set EnableViewState to false on the *page*, but you probably need to set it on specific *controls*.

So with it turned off for the page, none of the controls will maintain viewstate.  So selections and the like will not be maintained across postbacks.  If I understand your problem correctly, I think you need no view state on the comboboxes, and then you need viewstate on the checkoxlist.

Comment: Ahhh Ok I will try setting EnableViewState to true for the checkboxlist

Comment: Didn't work. I don't want to post the code because there is alot of it and when I do post it not all of it gets posted. :S

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you are setting the value to something persistent during the post back.